# How to display same property from different objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

I am doing a project which uses The Movie Db API and I am bit confused with displaying following object:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 12, name: "Adventure"}
1: {id: 28, name: "Action"}
2: {id: 878, name: "Science Fiction"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Basically, I am trying to figure out how to display those 3 genres in one element. Doing forEach loop like this :

```
const genreArr = data.genres;
console.log(genreArr)
genreArr.forEach(function(item){
    genre.textContent = item.name;
})
```

displays only one name of genre rather than all of them.
So, what do I have to do to display all of those in one paragraph?

Comment: you're overriding the last genre with the next one, consider using `+=`, or better, accumulate a string  and then set it once your done to avoid updating the dom multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `genre.textContent = item.name;` will overwrite the `textContent` every iteration of `forEach` leaving only the last value.

You need append to `textContent` using `+=`.

```js
const genreArr = [
  {id: 12, name: "Adventure"},
  {id: 28, name: "Action"},
  {id: 878, name: "Science Fiction"}
];

const genre = document.getElementById('genre');

genreArr.forEach(function(item){
    genre.textContent += item.name + ' | ';
})
```

```html
<div id="genre">

</div>
```

An alternate, more efficient method using `map()` and `join()`:

```js
const genreArr = [
  {id: 12, name: "Adventure"},
  {id: 28, name: "Action"},
  {id: 878, name: "Science Fiction"}
];

const genre = document.getElementById('genre');

/* Create an array containing only the 'name' values */
var genreNames = genreArr.map(function(item) {
  return item['name'];
});

/* Assign the names to the div in one go, with a seperator */
genre.textContent = genreNames.join(' | ');
```

```html
<div id="genre"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this

```
let arr = [];
let sentence = '';

genreArr.forEach(el => {
  arr.push(el.name);
  sentence += ' ' + el.name;
})

console.log(arr)
console.log(sentence)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and do your operation easily

```js
const arraryList = [{id: 12, name: "Adventure"},
{id: 28, name: "Action"},
{id: 878, name: "Science Fiction"}];

const output = arraryList.map(val => val.name);
const combinedName = output.join(",");
console.log(output);
console.log(combinedName);
```